# Simpler way of coding this

Tags: jquery-selectors

On this page: [of my website](http://www.4pixels.com/web-design/about-me.html#)

I have this jQuery, but it seems a bit long winded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").hide();
$("#lastfmrecords").hide();
$("h2.btn1 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn1>*").toggle(400);
});
$("h2.btn2 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn2>*").toggle(400);
});
$("h2.btn3 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn3>*").toggle(400);
});
$("h2.btn4 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn4>*").toggle(400);
});
$("h2.btn5 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn5>*").toggle(400);
});
  $("h2.btn6 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn6>*").toggle(400);
});
  $("h2.btn7 a").click(function(){
$("ol.btn7>*").toggle(400);
});
});
</script>

<h2 class="btn5"><a href="#">FAVOURITE Books</a></h2>
    <ol class="btn5">
      <p>Freakonomics, Bad Science, A Brief History of Nearly Everything, 100 years of Solitude, On Chesil Beach</p>
    </ol>
```

Then I have 7 ordered lists with those names, no. 5 above (btn1 - btn7) which toggle when I click on the H2 title that corresponds. All works fine, but is there a way of compacting the jQuery?

Comment: This seems like a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop seems like an obvious solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol').hide();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    $('h2.btn' + i + ' a').click(function() {
      $('ol.btn' + i + ' > *').toggle(400);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Blimey, that was quick :) Thanks Aistina, I'll give that a go. Cheers

Comment: I like it. For some reason people tend to avoid for loops in jQuery, just because it has its own "deal-with-all-these-things" functinality. Sometimes a for loop is just the best option.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can wrap the `h2`'s under a `div` and have your `<a> rel` to the class of the `ol` you wanna toggle

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <h2><a rel="btn1"> </a><ol class="btn1">...</ol>
   ...
   <h2><a rel="btn7"> </a><ol class="btn7">...</ol>
</div>
```

then do it as below, note that you also might want to prevent the browser to scroll to the top by passing in `event` object as the function argument and call `.preventDefault()`

```
$('.wrapper h2 a').click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('ol.' + $(this).attr('rel') + ' p').toggle(400); 
});
```

**EDIT:
If you'd prefer to keep your layout as is, you can also do something like:**

```
$('h2[class^=btn] > a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('ol.' + $(this).parent().attr('class') + ' > p').toggle(400);
});
```

Comment: Again, I'm impressed by the speed of you guys! Guess that's why I stick to design and not coding :/ Thanks to both of you.